# Issue with my recursive maze traversal algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

The purpose of my code is to create a program that will read in a maze and store it into a 2D array and solve it. I got the program to read the maze and put it into the array but my recursive algorithm is not working and this is the third different time I have changed it trying to get it to work. So could you help me get this to work?

Edit:I found out the problem with my original algorithm in the sense I got it to solve the maze but I have ran into another problem. The program is not printing out the correct things. Also this is just for my curiosity. I have already found out how to get it to work another way.

Maze Code:

```
 public static boolean goNorth(){
        boolean success;
        if (maze[currCol][currRow - 1] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]) {
            success = true;
            }
        if(maze[currCol][currRow - 1] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol][currRow - 1] = PATH;
            currRow = currRow - 1;
            success = goNorth();
                if(!success){
                success = goWest();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goEast();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currRow = currRow + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

    public static boolean goWest(){
        boolean success;
        if (maze[currCol - 1][currRow] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]) {
            success = true;
            }
        if(maze[currCol - 1][currRow] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol - 1][currRow] = PATH;
            currCol = currCol - 1;
            success = goWest();
                if(!success){
                success = goSouth();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goNorth();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currCol = currCol + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static boolean goEast(){
        boolean success;
        if (maze[currCol + 1][currRow] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]) {
            success = true;
            }
        if(maze[currCol + 1][currRow] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol + 1][currRow] = PATH;
            currCol = currCol + 1;
            success = goEast();
                if(!success){
                success = goNorth();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goSouth();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currCol = currCol - 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static boolean goSouth(){
        boolean success;
        if (maze[currCol][currRow + 1] == maze[finishCol][finishRow]){
            success = true;
            }
        if(maze[currCol][currRow + 1] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol][currRow + 1] = PATH;
            currRow = currRow + 1;
            success = goSouth();
                if(!success){
                success = goEast();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goWest();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currRow = currRow - 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Maze Solver Code:

```
public class SolveMaze1
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Maze1 maze = new Maze1();
        maze.readMaze();
        maze.printMaze();
        maze.goNorth();
        maze.printMaze();
    }
}
```

Desired outcome:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFx
x     x       xxxx x
x xxxxx xxxxx   xx x
x xxxxx xxxxxxx xx x
x            xx xx x
x xxxxxxxxxx xx    x
xxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxx

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFx
xVVVVVxPPPPPPPxxxxPx
xVxxxxxPxxxxxPPPxxPx
xVxxxxxPxxxxxxxPxxPx
xVVVVVVPPPPPPxxPxxPx
xVxxxxxxxxxxPxxPPPPx
xxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxx
```

My Outcome:

```
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFx
    xVVVVVxVVVVVVVxxxxVx
    xVxxxxxVxxxxxVVVxxVx
    xVxxxxxVxxxxxxxVxxVx
    xVVVVVVVVVVVVxxVxxVx
    xVxxxxxxxxxxVxxVVVVx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxSxxxxxxx
```

Comment: I've tried a while loop and a for loop.

Comment: It would help if you could use just one `go(dx,dy)` method. This would compress the code and less code always contains less bugs.

Comment: I am very new to JAVA and because of this I would not know exactly how to do this.

Comment: I had nearly the same exact assignment for my computer programming college program in Data Structures and Algorithms In C++. I was to read an existing maze into a 2d array and solve it using a recursive algorithm. It's actually not as complicated as it might seem.

Comment: Your code should not compile properly, as all your go-Methods don't have a return statement for the case that `maze[currCol - 1][currRow] == CLEAR`.

Comment: This is where you do this thing known as "debugging".  Or you give up and switch to art.

Comment: @HotLicks - Come on, everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: The code does compile. In the go methods the return statements are successes and the return false.

Comment: Thank you RustyTheBoyRobot.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot - Right.  And here is where Jaylon needs to start learning how to debug.

Comment: @Hot Licks This is very true but you kinda have to think about if I knew how to do that I would not be posting here. Thank you for putting in your input though it is much appreciated.

Comment: With all due respect, insert `println` statements and follow where your code is going.  Figure out where it's doing things you don't intend it to do.  This is the "grunt work" of programming.

Comment: @HotLicks - I get the humor and understand the need for debugging skills, I just don't think suggesting to give up is very good advice. Funny, but maybe not to a new learner.

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot - If you don't learn how to debug you might as well give up.  There is no programming without debugging.

Comment: Well I wouldn't say to just give up if you don't learn to debug. You must understand the importance. Debugging goes hand in hand with the development life cycle. You can't really perform one without the other. This is obviously a college/university assignment and they will require the understanding of debugging techniques the further you get in the program. The sooner you get it, the better off you will be especially when assignments become even more complex.

Comment: By the way, you can actually downsize your code there quite a bit further by doing what Rusty there has suggested in one of his comments.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of good advice in the comments; I'll just try and summarize them as best I can.

#### MePePeR's Advice: Use one method call

Transform your individual `goXXXX()` calls into a single `go(dx, dy)` call. If you are trying to tackle recursion (as your question suggests), you should probably be pretty familiar with writing your own methods first. Notice that each `goXXXX()` method is almost identical, except in each one you modify the `currCol` and `currRow` variables. If you pass in the amount of change as parameters (i.e., the change for `currCol` as `dx` and the change for `currRow` as `dy`), you can use the same method over and over, just giving it different values. A move east would be `go(1, 0)`, a move south would be `go(0, -1)`, etc.

If you aren't very comfortable with passing parameters, just give it a try, post the updated code and we can guide you through issues you encounter.

#### Hot Lick's advice: Use a debugger.

You've already taken the first step here with your `printMaze` method. If you aren't developing in an IDE (I didn't when I first started learning), debuggers can be a little hard to use. In that case, you'll need to simply use more `System.out.println` statements to get more information on the execution of your code. If you *are* using and IDE, start trying out the debugger. They're really easy to use once you start playing around with them. Once again, if you get stuck, talk to us and we can help guide you.

One last pointer: notice that your maze printout has this:

```
xVVx
PPVx
xPxx
```

Since you are only supposed to go north, south, east or west into a free space, how are you able to get a `V` in the upper right corner? It's an indication that your code is possibly either marking the wrong cell, or allowing a move that's illegal.

Comment: I am not using an IDE but I will try to use a debugger and I will also try to use just one method and I will post the updated code. Thank you everyone for your help and criticism.

Comment: I recommend Eclipse. It's a pain to use initially, but you can't beat the price. Plus there are plenty willing to help on the Internet.

Comment: I ended up using the one method call method. It made things a lot easier to code and made my code significantly smaller and more compact. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Determine what your base condition (case) is. In this case, your base case would probably be to determine if the present position (x, y) is greater than the ceiling, less than the floor, less than the left wall or greater than the right wall.

Next, you should probably determine if the present position (x, y) is the 'end of maze' character or treasure.

Then determine if the present position (x, y) is the 'start of maze' character.

At this point, I would have my algorithm draw a character in that position if all other conditions have been met.  This character would represent that the position has been visited.  Later on, you could choose to traverse the coordinates that you have collected and replace this character with a blank space if you choose.

The hard part is done. Now you call the method recursively, this time passing in the new coordinates, once for each direction you want your iterator/solver to go. Ex. if (checkPath(r, c-1) == true) // go west

At which point, you can now change the visited path of the maze to spaces. Ex. maze[r][c] = ' ';

This is the best I can do without giving you the entire answer.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No problem. Try to throw something together with what you have now, and see what you come up with. If you have further problems, I have no problem helping you out.

Comment: +1 - Recursive algorithms should always be defined with a base case and a recursive step.

Comment: While doing this debugging, start with a smaller, simpler maze; on the order of, say, 5x5. This will give you a smaller problem to solve and will make it easier to find bugs. Just MHO.