# OutOfMemoryException For Maze Solver of Large Dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays, maze

The Program Works for arrays upto 20x20 But for anything larger it throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Below is the code:

```
public static Point GetFinalPath(int x, int y) {

        queue.Enqueue(new Point(x,y, null));

        while(queue.Count>0) {
            Point p = queue.Dequeue();

            if (arr[p.x,p.y] == 9) {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Destination");
                return p;
            }

            if(IsOpen(p.x+1,p.y)) {
                arr[p.x,p.y] = 1;
                queue.Enqueue(new Point(p.x+1,p.y, p));
            }

            //similarly for the other directions


        }
        return null;
    }

public int[,] SolutionMaze()
            {
                Point p = GetFinalPath(0, 0);

                while (p.getParent() != null)
                {
                    solvedarray[p.x, p.y] = 9;
                    p = p.getParent();
                }
                return solvedarray;
            }
```

ok people here is the rest of the code

```
public static Queue<Point> queue=new Queue<Point>();

  public static bool IsOpen(int x, int y)
        {
            //BOUND CHECKING
            if ((x >= 0 && x < XMAX) && (y >= 0 && y < YMAX) && (arr[x,y] == 0 || arr[x,y] == 9))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
 public class Point
        {
           public int x;
           public int y;
            Point parent;

            public Point(int x, int y, Point parent)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.parent = parent;
            }

            public Point getParent()
            {
                return this.parent;
            }

        }
```

Assumes start to be 0,0 and final destination is set as 9 at the constructor.

Help me implement this for an array of size 500x500

Comment: Try provide full program (method `IsOpen` is missing, `solvedarray` variable is missing)

Comment: Oh, it seems that you have your defined class `Point`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it looks like you are not marking points you have already visited.  You are probably visiting the same points many times as you slowly expand out from the starting point, causing your queue to get huge before you find the target point.

Comment: visited points are marked 1 in the array and they wont be visited again

Comment: @nsinreal i have put the missing code

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if your `queue` contains the point already when you're adding them in every direction? It kinda feels like there's still something to your code that is missing.

Comment: While nsinreal provided a partial answer I don't believe that it's the real issue--even if every point was being hit 4 times you simply wouldn't be using anything like enough memory to run out.  Something must be running wild.

Comment: In a case like this I favor old-school debugging techniques--using a debugger on this is rather like trying to find a needle in a haystack.  Instead I would put a routine in that loop that writes to a log file the contents of the queue on each iteration.  I rather suspect an eyeball on the file will tell you what's up.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I see you don't understand. Every point isn't hit by constant value like 2x or 4x. It being hit many-many-many times. I showed an example of doubling single point on 2x2 labyrinth. Just try to count same point hits for 3x3 and 4x4. You will see that count of points in queue increases not linearly, as must be.

Comment: @nsinreal It seems to me you're showing a point can be hit from each neighbor.  That translates to 4x, not crazy-x.  Anyway, even if it does end up being crazy-x the approach I suggested will make it very obvious.

Comment: Perhaps the following will be of some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223464/issue-with-my-recursive-maze-traversal-algorithm/16224012#16224012

Comment: @JamesShaw will check your reference....
and i have already found my solution the code is mentioned below

Comment: @algaey Not a problem. Sorry, didn't see the solution till after I had posted the comment.  Please disregard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found an answer to the OutOfMemory. Now the code works even for 500x500 matrix
As it turns out i just implemented a node list which keeps track of added nodes in queue using y*MAX_X_LENGTH + x formula

```
public static Queue<Point> queue=new Queue<Point>();

        public SolveMaze(int[,] array,int staX,int staY,int finX,int finY)
        {
            //sets Destination as 9
            arr = array;
            XMAX = array.GetLength(0);
            YMAX = array.GetLength(1);
            finishY = finX; finishX = finY; startY = staX; startX = staY;
            solvedarray = new int[XMAX, YMAX];
        }

        public static List<int> nodelist=new List<int>();

        public void AddPointToQueueIfOpenAndNotAlreadyPresent(Point p,int direction)
        {
            if (nodelist.Contains(XMAX * p.y + p.x))
                return;
            else
            {
                switch(direction){
                case 1:
                    //north
                    if (IsOpen(p.x, p.y - 1))
                    {
                        arr[p.x, p.y] = 1;
                        queue.Enqueue(new Point(p.x, p.y - 1, p));
                        nodelist.Add(XMAX * (p.y - 1) + p.x);
                    }
                    break;
                case 0:
                    //east
                    if (IsOpen(p.x + 1, p.y))
                    {
                        arr[p.x, p.y] = 1;
                        queue.Enqueue(new Point(p.x + 1, p.y, p));
                        nodelist.Add(XMAX * (p.y) + p.x + 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //south
                    if (IsOpen(p.x, p.y + 1))
                    {
                        arr[p.x, p.y] = 1;
                        queue.Enqueue(new Point(p.x, p.y +1, p));
                        nodelist.Add(XMAX * (p.y + 1) + p.x);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //west
                    if (IsOpen(p.x - 1, p.y))
                    {
                        arr[p.x, p.y] = 1;
                        queue.Enqueue(new Point(p.x - 1, p.y, p));
                        nodelist.Add(XMAX * (p.y) + p.x-1);
                    }
                    break;                    }
            }
        }

        public Point GetFinalPath(int x, int y) {
            if (arr[finishX, finishY] == 0)
                arr[finishX, finishY] = 9;
            else
                return null;

                queue.Enqueue(new Point(x, y, null));
                nodelist.Add(XMAX * y + x);

        while(queue.Count>0) {
            Point p = queue.Dequeue();
            nodelist.Remove(p.y * XMAX + p.x);

            if (arr[p.x,p.y] == 9) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exit is reached!");
                return p;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                AddPointToQueueIfOpenAndNotAlreadyPresent(p, i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


        public static bool IsOpen(int x, int y)
        {
            //BOUND CHECKING
            if ((x >= 0 && x < XMAX) && (y >= 0 && y < YMAX) && (arr[x,y] == 0 || arr[x,y] == 9))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


            public int[,] SolutionMaze()
            {
                Point p = GetFinalPath(startX, startY);
                if(p!=null)
                while (p.getParent() != null)
                {
                    solvedarray[p.x, p.y] = 9;
                    p = p.getParent();
                }
                return solvedarray;
            }
    }

         public class Point
        {
           public int x;
           public int y;
            Point parent;

            public Point(int x, int y, Point parent)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.parent = parent;
            }

            public Point getParent()
            {
                return this.parent;
            }

        }
```

Comment: This isn't a forum but a Q&A site, if you found the answer post the answer and only the answer (not mixed with another question) and ask a new question separately

Comment: @RonanThibaudau will take your advise

Comment: It's better to create structure representing simple Point and use `HashSet` to get significant speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your code I found one problem. You perform the wrong check. You should check if your point is already added to a queue. What do you do now? We'll, you are just marking processed cell as not open. It's easy to see that you can add to queue same node twice.

Let's follow my example:

```
1 | . .
0 | ! .
--+----
yx| 0 1
Queue: point (0,0)
```

We are starting at point(0,0). At this moment, we are adding points (0, 1) and (1,0) to our queue and mark point(0,0) as processed

```
1 | . .
0 | X !
--+----
yx| 0 1
Queue: point (0,1), point (1,0)
```

Now we dequeue point(0,1), marking it processed and adding point(1,1) to queue.

```
1 | ! .
0 | X X
--+----
yx| 0 1
Queue: point (1,0), point(1,1)
```

Now we dequeue point(1,0), marking it as processed and adding point(1,1) to queue:

```
1 | X !
0 | X X
--+----
yx| 0 1
Queue: point (1,1), point (1,1)
```

And now we have same point twice in a queue. And that is not your last problem. Your points have a reference to all it parents, so your previous points (doubled too) can't be processed with Garbage Collector.

Comment: Im currently trying to implement node numbers..
How would u proceed to solve the issue

Comment: @algaey In a related situation I handled it by queueing all possible points and checking if they were already processed when they were dequeued.